# What C/C++ library do I use to change an HTTP packet in windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, networking

It seems winpcap can't be used to do this kind of job([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802186/how-do-i-modify-a-http-response-packet-with-winpcap/2832288#2832288)),

then which library to use alternatively?

Answer (score 1):

This is very interesting. Look what I found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider)

> A Layered Service Provider (LSP) is a
>   feature of the Microsoft Windows
>   Winsock 2 Service Provider Interface
>   (SPI). A Layered Service Provider is a
>   DLL that uses Winsock APIs to insert
>   itself into the TCP/IP stack. Once in
>   the stack, a Layered Service Provider
>   can intercept and modify inbound and
>   outbound Internet traffic.

Comment: @user198729: no, I just found out about this. I will play with it when time permits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some tools to filter, modify, sniff packets in windows:

1. [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/divert.html) Free open source project work on Windows 7, 2008 or
   upper. network layer.
2. [WinpkFilter 3.0](http://www.ntkernel.com/w&p.php?id=7) Commercial, Windows XP and upper. datalink
   layer
3. [pcausa](http://pcausa.com/), Commercial. datalink layer
4. [Windows Filtering Platform Packet Modification Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) A sample
   to create callout driver that WinDivert use, you should now to
   implement kernel driver. network layer.